# $("html").animate does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code for scrolling to top with the smooth animation. This works fine in Mozilla and IE browsers, but in chrome it is not working. Can any one please help.

```
$("#animate_top a").click(function(){   
    $("html").animate({scrollTop : 0},'slow');  
});
```

I have added the sample url, click "click to reach bottom" and click the "top" link at the bottom in chrome, mozilla and ie.

http://www.sanatanapublications.org/demo/sample.html

Comment: In general trying to animate those sorts of elements can lead to problems, especially in WebKit browsers.

Answer (score 5):

For cross-browser scrolling, use this:

`$('html,body')`

If you set a callback on the animation, it will fire twice in IE so you need to use a conditional statement for IE in your HTML:

Then load a script file that sets it to only use the 'body' element.

Comment: Thanks jackson, IE browser it is working, but chrome it is not working

Comment: Try adding quotes like this... {'scrollTop': '0'}

Comment: yes this is the code i'm using $("#animate_top a").click(function(){   
    $("html").animate({scrollTop : 0},'slow');  
});

Comment: hey jack after adding $('html, body') it is animating in chrome

Comment: Awesome, that's what I figured.

Comment: When you scroll in your browser, the browser is scrolling a specific element. Firefox and Opera scroll the HTML element. Chrome & Safari scroll the BODY element. IE scrolls both at once, that's a bug that got fixed in IE 10. Now IE 10 scrolls the BODY element.

Answer (score 4):

Try it with `$('body')` instead. If it still does not give the expected result, can you put up a public sample?

Comment: yes i have added it in public, please check                              I have added the sample url, click "click to reach bottom" and click the "top" link at the bottom in chrome, mozilla and ie.

http://www.sanatanapublications.org/demo/sample.html

Comment: here on my osx 10.6 with chrome 19.0.1084.52 it's giving exactly the same result in firefox and chrome.

Comment: i'm also have the same version of chrome, but it does not animate in chrome. I'm using windows 7 OS.